# Is it possible to use different `firestore.rules` for the emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I'm trying to run an end-to-end testing of my application with the Firebase emulator running to provide proper data and backend context.

Because of my security rules, I cannot put data into the emulator for the testing. Therefore, I tried to apply a special `firestore.rules` file to the emulator for testing, allowing all firebase access. However, the emulator does not use my testing rules file, `firestore.test.rules`,

I set the `firebase.json` like below.

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules", // the one with intense rules.
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log",
        "test",
        "emulator-data"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run test",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": [
    {
      // some hosting settings.
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5002
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "rules": "firestore.test.rules" // all-access rules.
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true,
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    }
  }
}
```

The emulator keep uses the `firebase.rules`, not `firestore.test.rules`.
Am I misunderstanding the `firebase.json` correctly?

FYI, I do not use `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` because I need my app (React-Native, Expo) and the jest environment to share the firestore environments, which seems impossible with `rules-unit-testing`.

How can I specify rules for the emulator??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an admin user and the rules will be bypassed.

The way to do it differs whether you are on v8 or v9, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests

Comment: I have a question about the test environment. When I create a test environment and add documents to the environment, does it make changes to the emulator's Firestore? It seems like it doesn't. I added a document using a test environment in Jest. My app connected to the Firebase emulator and tried to fetch the document but couldn't find it. It seems like the test environment acts like a sandbox, so the changes are not applied globally in the emulator but only to the environment itself.

Comment: So many things could be the issue. Can you create a new question on SO and add some code? Also if my reply answers your question, accept it so this thread is closed.